# Непонятное поведение массива при передаче его в метод

Tags: c#, массивы

Передаю массив в метод SwapArrayRow, по возвращению из которого передаваемый массив не изменяется. Не понимаю почему, массив это ссылочный тип данных => метод работает по факту с самим передаваемым массивом, а не с какой не копией. В-общем, я в полном замешательстве... К слову говоря если вызывать SwapArrayColumn, то все ок.

```
double[,] matrix = new double[3, 3] {
            { 0, 0, 1},
            { 1, -5, 0},
            { 3, 4, 2}}; 

SwapArrayColumn(matrix, 0, 2);

/// <summary>
    /// Возвращает транспонированную матрицу. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="matrix">Двумерный массив, представляющий собой матрицу.</param>
    public static double[,] Transpose(double[,] matrix)
    {
        double[,] matrixTranspose = new double[matrix.GetLength(1), matrix.GetLength(0)];

        for (int i =0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)    // i - строки обрабатываемой матрицы
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)    // j - элементы строки обрабатываемой матрицы
            {
                matrixTranspose[j, i] = matrix[i, j];
            }
        }

        return matrixTranspose;
    }

/// <summary>
    /// Меняет местами колонки m и n в указанном массиве. 
    /// </summary>
    private static void SwapArrayColumn(double[,] matrix, int m, int n)
    {
        if (m > matrix.GetLength(0) - 1 || n > matrix.GetLength(0) - 1)
            return;

        double[] tempArray = new double[matrix.GetLength(0)];

        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.GetLength(0); a++)    
        {
            tempArray[a] = matrix[a, m];
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.GetLength(0); a++)    
        {
            matrix[a, m] = matrix[a, n];
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.GetLength(0); a++)    
        {
            matrix[a, n] = tempArray[a];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Меняет местами строки m и n в указанном массиве. 
    /// </summary>
    private static void SwapArrayRow(double[,] matrix, int m, int n)
    {
        if (m > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1 || n > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1) 
            return;

        matrix = Transpose(matrix);
        SwapArrayColumn(matrix, m, n);
        matrix = Transpose(matrix);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы все равно передаете в массив копию ссылки на массив. В случае с `SwapArrayColumn` вы производите манипуляции с одной ссылкой на массив, в случае с SwapArrayRow вы вызываете другие функции которые оперируют с копией массива. Более [подробно](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) про передачу по ссылке и по значению^

Вот как правильно объявить ваш метод:

```
private static void SwapArrayRow(ref double[,] matrix, int m, int n)
    {
        if (m > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1 || n > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1) 
            return;

        matrix = Transpose(matrix);

        SwapArrayColumn(matrix, m, n);

        matrix = Transpose(matrix);

    }
```

Не могу не отметить, что для обмена двух колонок или рядов массива не нужны такие сложные действия. Вот пример реализации:

```
private static void SwapArrayColumn(ref double[,] matrix, int m, int n)
    {
        if (m > matrix.GetLength(0) - 1 || n > matrix.GetLength(0) - 1)
            return;

        double temp;

        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.GetLength(0); a++)    
        {
            temp = matrix[a, m];
            matrix[a,m]=matrix[a, n];
            matrix[a,n]=temp;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Меняет местами строки m и n в указанном массиве. 
    /// </summary>
    private static void SwapArrayRow(ref double[,] matrix, int m, int n)
    {
        if (m > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1 || n > matrix.GetLength(1) - 1) 
            return;

        double temp;

        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.GetLength(1); a++)    
        {
            temp = matrix[m,a];
            matrix[m,a]=matrix[n,a];
            matrix[n,a]=temp;
        }

    }
```

Пример вызова

```
SwapArrayColumn(ref matrix, 0, 2);
SwapArrayRow(ref matrix, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. А на счет реализации вы так же несомненно правы, с созданием буферного массива я действительно немного намудрил.